# Using QVariantAnimation to show a list of images

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have some trouble using QVariantAnimation. I've been searching exactly how to use it, but I just don't understand what to do. The documentation and the examples that I read are confusing me more.

I have a list of png images, and I want them to move from point A to point B and change the image depending on the step that I define, within a certain time.

An example would be, Point A is (0, 0) - Point B is (6, 0) and step is (2, 0).

From (0, 0) to (2, 0) display Image1

From (2, 0) to (4, 0) display Image2

From (4, 0) to (6, 0) display Image3

Giving this example as I don't understand QVariantAnimation past giving them the start and the end points.

Comment: I guess you're pointing to a QGraphicsPixmapItem in a QGraphicsView. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, I am using a QGraphicsPixmapItem inside a Scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to implement what you point out(the distance is very small so I have changed the dimensions).

- This method for each section is a QVariantAnimation that establishes a new QPixmap.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import random


def create_pixmap():
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(QtCore.QSize(20, 20))
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)))
    return pixmap


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(
            QtCore.QRectF(-200, -200, 400, 400), self
        )
        view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.m_scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)

        self.m_pixmap_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.m_scene.addItem(self.m_pixmap_item)

        datas = [
            (QtCore.QPointF(0, 40), create_pixmap()),
            (QtCore.QPointF(0, 80), create_pixmap()),
            (QtCore.QPointF(0, 120), create_pixmap()),
        ]

        self.data_iter = iter(datas)
        self.move()

    def move(self):
        try:
            end_point, pixmap = next(self.data_iter)
            self.m_pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap)

            animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
                duration=500,
                valueChanged=self.m_pixmap_item.setPos,
                finished=self.move,
                startValue=self.m_pixmap_item.pos(),
                endValue=end_point,
                parent=self,
            )
            animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
        except StopIteration:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- In this method, the itemChange method is overridden so that it changes from QPixmap to each section.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import random


def create_pixmap():
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(QtCore.QSize(20, 20))
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)))
    return pixmap


class GraphicsPixmapItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsPixmapItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)

        self.m_pixmaps = [create_pixmap() for _ in range(3)]

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            y = self.pos().y()
            if 0 <= y < 40:
                self.change_pixmap(self.m_pixmaps[0])
            elif 40 <= y < 80:
                self.change_pixmap(self.m_pixmaps[1])
            elif 80 <= y < 120:
                self.change_pixmap(self.m_pixmaps[2])
        return super(GraphicsPixmapItem, self).itemChange(change, value)

    def change_pixmap(self, pixmap):
        if self.pixmap() != pixmap:
            self.setPixmap(pixmap)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(
            QtCore.QRectF(-200, -200, 400, 400), self
        )
        view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.m_scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)

        self.m_pixmap_item = GraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.m_scene.addItem(self.m_pixmap_item)

        animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            duration=3000,
            valueChanged=self.m_pixmap_item.setPos,
            startValue=self.m_pixmap_item.pos(),
            endValue=QtCore.QPointF(0, 120),
            parent=self,
        )
        animation.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If I implement this with Key signals should I be able to press a Key and then press another while the loop of animation is playing? Would it interrupt the loop and then play another animation?

Comment: @BlackMage That depends on what you want to do, you can stop the animation with stop.

Comment: Also, are the QPointF the distance you would sum to the actual position? Because when I change the points with something in both X and Y, but with the same Y I thought It would advance in the same position Y but move through X. But it moves nothing like that.

Comment: @BlackMage QPointF is a class that stores the coordinates. On the other point I can not point to anything because I do not understand you, provide an [MCVE]

Comment: I changed the QPointF to (40, 20) - (80, 20) - (120, 20) respectively and it moves like a curve.

Comment: @BlackMage If you use the first code you will see that first it goes from (0, 0) (initial position by default) to (40, 20) in a straight line that is a diagonal then it goes to the point (80, 20) horizontally, and the same for (120, 20)