# PyQT5 QAbstractVideoSurface: Play Video with alpha channel (on windows)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, alpha, qvideowidget

I want to play a video in PyQT with a transparent background using QAbstractVideoSurface.

I have found a program which works on Linux on this topic : [Video with alpha channel overlay on background image: Alpha shows black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446585/video-with-alpha-channel-overlay-on-background-image-alpha-shows-black?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**...but in windows it does not work and the background is black.**

**
Here's the script :**

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class VideoWidget(QWidget):
    image = QImage()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(640, 480)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        # ensure that smooth transformation is used while scaling pixmaps
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.SmoothPixmapTransform)

        # provide compliancy with background set using stylesheets, see:
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, qp, self)

        # draw the image, scaled to the widget size; if you need fixed sizes
        # or keep aspect ratio, implement this (or the widget) accordingly
        qp.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())

class AlphaVideoDrawer(QAbstractVideoSurface):

    def __init__(self, videoWidget=None, widgetOptions=None):
        super().__init__()
        if videoWidget:
            if not hasattr(videoWidget, 'setImage'):
                raise NotImplementedError(
                    'setImage() must be implemented for videoWidget!')
        else:
            if not isinstance(widgetOptions, dict):
                widgetOptions = {}
            elif not 'styleSheet' in widgetOptions:
                # just a default background for testing purposes
                widgetOptions = {'styleSheet': 'background: darkGray;'}
            videoWidget = VideoWidget(**widgetOptions)
        self.videoWidget = videoWidget

        # QVideoFrame.image() has been introduced since Qt 5.15
        version, majVersion, minVersion = map(int, QT_VERSION_STR.split('.'))
        if version < 6 and majVersion < 15:
            self.imageFromFrame = self._imageFromFrameFix
        else:
            self.imageFromFrame = lambda frame: frame.image()

    def _imageFromFrameFix(self, frame):
        clone_frame = QVideoFrame(frame)
        clone_frame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly)
        image = QImage(
            clone_frame.bits(), frame.width(), frame.height(), frame.bytesPerLine(), 
            QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(frame.pixelFormat()))
        clone_frame.unmap()
        return image

    def supportedPixelFormats(self, type):
        return [QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32]

    def present(self, frame: QVideoFrame):
        if frame.isValid():
            self.videoWidget.setImage(self.imageFromFrame(frame))

        if self.surfaceFormat().pixelFormat() != frame.pixelFormat() or \
            self.surfaceFormat().frameSize() != frame.size():
                self.setError(QAbstractVideoSurface.IncorrectFormatError)
                self.stop()
                return False
        else:
            return True


class AlphaVideoTest(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QFrame#mainFrame {
                background: blue;
            }
        ''')

        mainFrame = QFrame(objectName='mainFrame')
        self.setCentralWidget(mainFrame)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(mainFrame)
        self.playButton = QPushButton('Play', checkable=True)
        layout.addWidget(self.playButton)

        self.drawer = AlphaVideoDrawer()
        layout.addWidget(self.drawer.videoWidget)

        self.mediaPlayer1 = QMediaPlayer(self, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist(self)
        path = QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('vida1test.mov')
        self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)))
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist.CurrentItemInLoop)

        self.mediaPlayer1.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
        self.mediaPlayer1.setVideoOutput(self.drawer)

        self.playButton.toggled.connect(self.togglePlay)

    def togglePlay(self, play):
        if play:
            self.mediaPlayer1.play()
            self.playButton.setText('Pause')
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer1.pause()
            self.playButton.setText('Play')

import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
test = AlphaVideoTest()
test.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried with .mov, .avi, and webm files with VP8 and VP9 codec but it did not work at all.
I have also installed K-Lite Codec Pack on my windows to read these files.

Is it even possible ?

Thank you very much if you can help me !

Comment: Are you sure that the videos you're trying *do* have transparency? The linked post specifically uses the a video format (yuva444p10le) that supports a 16-bit alpha channel. Most video formats/codecs do not support transparency (and some containers don't support the codecs that do). If your files do *not* have an alpha channel, then the black screen is a consequence, since the video surface (returned by `supportedPixelFormats()` only supports ARGB (Alpha+RGB). If they do have an alpha channel instead, it may be a problem of the backend, which may not be able to use that color space.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your time !
The videos I'm trying to use actually have alpha channel (as you can see [here](https://youtu.be/NR9jitPoXXI) for example).

The video format used in the post is ap4h which works on my linux, and when I tried with my VP9 webm, avi, etc. it did not work at all (on my linux too, I did a mistake in my previous post).  May it be because it supports "a 16-bit alpha channel" as you said or is it something else?

Last question: do you think PyQT can't support this video format, or that there are errors in the code? @musicamante

Comment: PyQt is just a binding, so has nothing to do with it. You have to look for the Qt API support, and for QtMultimedia in Qt5 this depends on the used backend: until Qt6.5, it used the system backend by default (GStreamer on linux, AVFoundation on apple, WMF on Windows, MediaCodec on Android), 6.4 introduced the ffmpeg backend which is default since 6.5. This could mean that your system backend could not support conversion to `Format_ARGB32`. Look at the available [`PixelFormat`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#PixelFormat-enum) enum, it contains other formats that support transparency.

Comment: You could then try to add those formats to the list provided by `supportedPixelFormats()`. Also, the code you used was specifically written (by me ;-) ) to check for formats and properly set an error on the video surface, so you should verify that too. A basic `print(...)` within the `if` of `present()` would provide further insight if the format is not compatible or, eventually, to check if the function is actually called at all (since the backend may not support the format to begin with, and therefore never proceed in *trying* to present the frame at all).

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations, very interesting and it helps me a lot. I'm going to try what you advised me to do, thanks again.